# Selenium go to url with url parameters

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

In one of my selenium tests, I'm trying to go to a url that has some url parameters, like so:

https://somewebsite.com/page?param1=something&param2=moreThings

The only issue is when i use Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://somewebsite.com/page?param1=something&param2=moreThings")

instead it goes to: https://somewebsite.com/page

does anyone know how i can get selenium to go to a url with the url parameters please.

Comment: I have never had this problem. Are you sure the website is not looking for some cookies? Are you able to share the _actual_ URL?

Comment: In general the issue with this should be Website specific and not Selenium.  If you can please share the exact URL you are attempting to navigate to that might help.  WebDriver should pass a URL and the browser will merely execute a navigate to that URL...everything else should be the Website causing a redirect to the other base URL.  I usually see this with login timeouts...

Comment: This is happening to me to. Too bad there isn't an answer.

Comment: Actually, with me it was a url typo and due to the typo, javascript was removing the URL. WebDriver was not a problem.